# Can't chain match_phrase_prefix in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to chain more than one match_phrase_prefix queries, but
for some reason it doesn't return any results (also no errors). When i try just 
one match_phrase_prefix everything works just fine. I am using Elastic Search version 2.3 and my query looks like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "title": "נפ"
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "sub_title": "נפצ"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

my mapping for the specific index is:

```
{
"wcm_articles": {
  "mappings": {
     "article": {
        "properties": {
           "approved_talkbacks_counter": {
              "type": "integer"
           },
           "article_link": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "author": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "hebrew"
           },
           "category_id": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "date_updated": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
           },
           "is_old": {
              "type": "boolean"
           },
           "is_promoted": {
              "type": "boolean"
           },
           "is_video": {
              "type": "boolean"
           },
           "last_update_user": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "launch_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
           },
           "plain_text": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "hebrew"
           },
           "promotion_notes": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "status": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "sub_title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "hebrew"
           },
           "tags": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "hebrew"
           },
           "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "waiting_talkbacks_counter": {
              "type": "integer"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}
}

And some example documents are:

```
"_index": "wcm_articles",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "2828280",
        "_score": 2.5246792,
        "_source": {
           "tags": [],
           "category_id": 3,
           "sub_title": "",
           "promotion_notes": "",
           "is_old": false,
           "last_update_user": "",
           "status": 1,
           "type": "article",
           "plain_text": "",
           "launch_date": null,
           "waiting_talkbacks_counter": 0,
           "approved_talkbacks_counter": 0,
           "is_video": false,
           "article_link": "",
           "date_updated": "2016-12-05T15:12:10",
           "title": "קשישה כבת 80 נפצעה קשה מפגיעת רכב בחולון ",
           "author": "",
           "is_promoted": false

"_index": "wcm_articles",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "2829275",
        "_score": 2.1283152,
        "_source": {
           "tags": [],
           "category_id": 3,
           "sub_title": "",
           "promotion_notes": "",
           "is_old": false,
           "last_update_user": "",
           "status": 1,
           "type": "article",
           "plain_text": "",
           "launch_date": null,
           "waiting_talkbacks_counter": 0,
           "approved_talkbacks_counter": 0,
           "is_video": false,
           "article_link": "",
           "date_updated": "2016-12-05T15:12:16",
           "title": "רוכבת אופנוע נפצעה קשה בתאונת דרכים בצומת סירקין בפ\"ת",
           "author": "",
           "is_promoted": false
```

Comment: Could you please share your mapping with some data-samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my issue is solved. There was no problem with chaining the queries. I was not using "match_phrase_prefix" the correct way, it wont work with a single word, only when you use it with more than one word, for a single word the correct query for the purpose of a form of autocomplete search (a search that includes a part of a word and not a whole word) is - "prefix". when chaining any combination of these two and used correctly for each - there is no problem at all.

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: How does the query look like after the fix ?

Comment: I will post it in a few hours